# setup:upgrade command is not running

Tags: magento2.3.2, setup-upgrade

I am using magento 2.3.2 and installed the theme and enable the theme module but i am not able to run the **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command.
please check the below image

[image]

Any Solution please
Note: var and pub folders permissions are changed to 777

Comment: What you get if you run `php bin/magento`

Comment: same as setup:upgrade command

Comment: check the `bin` permissions

Comment: 755 permission for bin